# Личное местоимение против "как"

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Я()как Бэтмен,но не мышь.

Я() как злой гений, только добрый.

Я вижу запятую после личных местоимений в огромном количестве предложений.

Но :

"если без сравнительного оборота теряется смысл предложения,то запятая не ставится"

Разве тут смысл не потеряется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь "как Бэтман" и "как злой гений" - сказуемые, поэтому запятые не ставятся, хотя это сравнительные обороты

Answer (score 2):

Сравнительный оборот может являться именной частью сказуемого, тогда запятая не ставится, например: "Земная слава как дым, не этого я просила".

Но при наличии паузы можно поставить тире, например: "Я весь – как взмах неощутимых крыл".

Тогда получим: Я - как Бэтмен,но не мышь. Я - как злой гений, только добрый.